# How can I get a list of apps installed, but not including system apps?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check if an app is a non-system app in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784505/how-do-i-check-if-an-app-is-a-non-system-app-in-android)

At the moment this code returns everything including system apps like the Android System and clock.

```
public List<ApplicationInfo> getApps() {
        final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
                .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        return packages;
    }
```

How can I differentiate between these and user-installed apps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784505/how-do-i-check-if-an-app-is-a-non-system-app-in-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi you can use the code below

```
 for(ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
        //checks for flags; if flagged, check if updated system app
        if((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) == 1) {
            installedApps.add(app);
        //it's a system app, not interested
        } else if ((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
            //Discard this one
        //in this case, it should be a user-installed app
        } else {
            installedApps.add(app);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what means of 'FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP' @Talha