# Get running Apps(Internal and External) with icons

Tags: android, activity-manager

Currently, I'm working on to get a list of all running applications. I've been able to do this in the following way,

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mInfo);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> listOfRunningProcess = activityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();
Log.d(TAG, "XXSize: " + listOfRunningProcess.size());
l1 = findViewById(R.id.Layout1);
for (RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : listOfRunningProcess) {
    if (runningAppProcessInfo.uid > 1026) {
        uID = runningAppProcessInfo.uid;
        Log.d(TAG, "ANS " + runningAppProcessInfo.processName + " Id :"
            + runningAppProcessInfo.pid + " UID: " + uID);
    }
}
```

It gives a list of all running applications. Now I want to differentiate these applications on the basis of whether they are Internal or External apps. Is there any way to separate out internal and external apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784505/how-do-i-check-if-an-app-is-a-non-system-app-in-android) is the thread which checks the whether the app is system app or not.

so that if you get the list of apps then you can check the apps whether the apps are system apps or not using the above thread. so that you can separate the apps.